# HTML doesn't take full width

Tags: css, html, mobile

I've got a problem with my website. `<html>` doesn't take full width on mobile.

I'm using Bootstrap + Jquery.

Do you know where my problem comes from .

Thanks !

[image: Views screenshot]

Comment: Post your code here in the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your viewport is off. To correct it, add this meta tag to your `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For more information on the Viewport meta tag, see [this MDN 
page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is the causing the issue

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> <!--this adds negative margin.-->
    <div class="col-x-*">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The structure is compulsory when using bootstrap.